# Invoking java methods in XML in android

Tags: java, android, xml

I am making an app that generates random numbers for android (you can find it hat https://github.com/JXPheonix/RNumGen ) and I need some way for an xml string to be dynamic (of sorts); it needs to change every time it is viewed.

I want the string to invoke a method that generates a random number. The string in my xml file goes something like this:

```
    <string name="number">Your number is</string>
```

and I want after the is for a method in java to be called upon, which would subsequently change the ending of the string. Any way to do this (whether or not it involves actually editing the strings.xml file?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going about it a round-about way. Instead of somehow making your string in your XML file dynamic, just use your string and append to it in code. Something like:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
textView.setText(getString(R.string.number) + yourRNGMethod());
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't change the string, concatenate the constant string with your generated number in your code.

Alternatively, use the string as an input to String.format and use a placeholder for the number.

Comment: Thats sort of helpful, but what do you means when you say "with the generated number"? How would you go about doing this? Sorry, but I'm admittedly a java novice. Would I create a new string, and then, in the main xml file, display them both next to each other? Or would I display them both in java? Basically for me this would be great: <string name=generatednumber>gen()</string? but I realize that wouldnt work so how would I do the equivalent of this? Also, the number will be saved as a variable and the method will return that int or a parsed version of the int into a String.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use the strings.xml for strings which have changing values.

Its not clear what the scope for consumption of your random number is but you can always use the Math classes to generate a random number and then Integer.toString() the value to get the value as a string.